# Find matching keys in dictionaries & replace keys with values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I need to compare the keys and if the keys match, I need to replace the second dictionary keys with the values from the first.

```
d1 = {'22': 'Jane', '33': 'Tom', '44': 'John', '55': 'Laura'}    
d2 = {'22': {'Lilly', 'Jake'}, '33' : {'Janet'}, '44': {'Tim'}}
```

I started, but something is already wrong...

```
for k, v in d2.items():
    d2[k] = d1(k, v)
    print(d2)
```

It should look like this:

```
{'Jane': {'Lilly', 'Jake'}, 'Tom': {'Janet'}, 'John': {'Tim'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension that iterates over the set intersection of the keys of the two dicts and output the corresponding values as the keys and values of the new dict:

```
{d1[k]: d2[k] for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
```

This returns:

```
{'Tom': {'Janet'}, 'Jane': {'Jake', 'Lilly'}, 'John': {'Tim'}}
```

Sets are unordered, however. If you would like to preserve the key order of `d2` (as keys are ordered since Python 3.7), you can iterate over the items of `d2` instead:

```
{d1[k]: v for k, v in d2.items() if k in d1}
```

This returns:

```
{'Jane': {'Lilly', 'Jake'}, 'Tom': {'Janet'}, 'John': {'Tim'}}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:
1) Iterate through the key values in the first dictionary
2) If the key value exists as a key in the second dictionary, then create a new entry for the value of the *first* dictionary's key, and delete the entry of the old key.

This worked for me:

```
d1 = {'22': 'Jane', '33': 'Tom', '44': 'John', '55': 'Laura'}

d2 = {'22': {'Lilly', 'Jake'}, '33' : {'Janet'}, '44': {'Tim'}}

for key in d1:
    if key in d2:
        d2[d1[key]] = d2[key]
        del d2[key]
```