# Combine two dictionaries and replace keys with values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to combine two list and replace key with values of other dictionary, see below:

**Input:**

```
d1 = {'22': ['Jane','test'], '33': ['Tom','Hary','Jonas'], '44': ['John']}
d2 = {'22': ['K:Lilly', 'K:Jake'], '33' : ['A:Janet','Brian'], '44': ['Tim','Brian']}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
 'K:Lilly': ['Jane', 'test'], 
 'K:Jake': ['Jane', 'test'], 
 'A:Janet': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas'], 
 'Brian': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas','John'], 
 'Tim': ['John']
}
```

I tried similar approaches but no success:
[Find matching keys in dictionaries & replace keys with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250464/find-matching-keys-in-dictionaries-replace-keys-with-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `dict.setdefault`:

```
d3 = {}
for k, v in d2.items():
    for k2 in v:
        if k in d1:
            d3.setdefault(k2, []).extend(d1[k])
print(d3)
```

Output:

```
{'K:Lilly': ['Jane', 'test'],
 'K:Jake': ['Jane', 'test'],
 'A:Janet': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas'],
 'Brian': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas', 'John'],
 'Tim': ['John']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```py
d1 = {'22': ['Jane','test'], '33': ['Tom','Hary','Jonas'], '44': ['John']}
d2 = {'22': ['K:Lilly', 'K:Jake'], '33' : ['A:Janet','Brian'], '44': ['Tim','Brian']}

output = {}

for k1, v1 in d1.items():
    v2 = d2.get(k1)
    if(v2 != None): # extra caution if the key does not exist in d2
        for i in v2:
            if(i in output):
                output[i].extend(v1) # key already exist, just extend
            else:
                output[i] = v1.copy() # careful to make a copy
                
print(output)
```

```
{'K:Lilly': ['Jane', 'test'], 
'K:Jake': ['Jane', 'test'], 
'A:Janet': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas'], 
'Brian': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas', 'John'], 
'Tim': ['John']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'22': ['Jane','test'], '33': ['Tom','Hary','Jonas'], '44': ['John']}
d2 = {'22': ['K:Lilly', 'K:Jake'], '33' : ['A:Janet','Brian'], '44': ['Tim','Brian']}
newDict = {}
for key2 in d2:
    values = d1[key2]
    for val2 in d2[key2]:
        newDict[val2] = d1[key2].copy()
        
print(newDict)
```

Comment: Does not give the desired output for key `Brian`.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output, it seems that you only want the names (values) of d2 as keys in the result with the corresponding values of d1 as values for these names.  This can be obtained with a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
d1 = {'22': ['Jane','test'], '33': ['Tom','Hary','Jonas'], '44': ['John']}
d2 = {'22': ['K:Lilly', 'K:Jake'], '33' : ['A:Janet','Brian'], '44': ['Tim','Brian']}

d3 = { name:d1[key] for key,names in d2.items() for name in names }  

print(d3)

{'K:Lilly': ['Jane', 'test'], 'K:Jake': ['Jane', 'test'], 
 'A:Janet': ['Tom', 'Hary', 'Jonas'], 'Brian': ['John'], 
 'Tim': ['John']}
```