# Find matching keys in dictionary and nested array & replace array with values from

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have sort of a similar question as [Find matching keys in dictionaries & replace keys with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250464/find-matching-keys-in-dictionaries-replace-keys-with-values)

However my situation looks like this.

```
d1 = {"1": "DNS Compromise", "2": "DNS Poisoning", "3": "Fraud Orders"}
d2 = {... ,"categories": [1, 2], ...}
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
d2 = {..., "categories": [DNS Compromise, DNS Poisoning], ...}
```

Is there a way to construct a for loop or use comprehension? I am sort of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

With dictionary you can easily get a list of the values with the method `values()`.

```
d2 = {"categories": d1.values()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you are searching for :
`d3 = {k:[ d1[str(v_i)] for v_i in v] for k,v in d2.items() }`